# Objective C: request for member in something not a structure or union

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm new to Cocoa development and the following error is puzzling me:

```
request for member 'mainWindow' in something not a structure or union
```

My AppDelegate.h looks like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject
{
    IBOutlet NSWindow *mainWindow;
}
```

And the code which causes the error is this in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *) aNotification
{
    NSView *view = mainWindow.contentView;     // gives compiler error above
    printf("MAIN WINDOW: %p\n", mainWindow);   // works fine
}
```

Note that the printf() line works fine which shows me that 'mainWindow' is accessible but why does the line above fail then? I mean, 'mainWindow' has clearly been defined as "NSWindow*"... so how can this fail?

It's probably very obvious for you Cocoa experts but I'm sorry, I just don't see it :/

Comment: Compiles just fine for me, so I have to wonder if something else is going on.

Comment: I have to add that I'm on a very old XCode version (2.1) and targetting Mac OS 10.4 for PowerPC architecture. Still, I don't see what's wrong there. As soon as I remove the line shown above, everything compiles and runs fine.

Comment: "I have to add that I'm on a very old XCode version (2.1) and targetting Mac OS 10.4 for PowerPC architecture." You certainly do.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't expect that such lowlevel things like language syntax and new syntactic sugar were still evolving. But after all, that was the reason because the Xcode 2.1 gcc doesn't like mainWindow.contentView but needs [mainWindow contentView] instead.

Comment: Yep, exactly. You are using Objective-C-2.0 syntax, but you are pre-Objective-C-2.0. That fact is crucial!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive the error because you're trying to access an iVar as a property. Access it as iVar and the problem goes away.

Edit: an instance variable is accessed either via self->someVariable, or directly as someVariable, assuming there is no other local variables named someVariable. The arrow notation is needed as self represents a pointer, thus if your class is MyClass, self has the type *MyClass. A property on the other hand can be accessed as self.propertyName.

Comment: As I said, I'm new to Cocoa development so could you explain this a little further? I suppose "iVar" means "instance variable"? So how should I access this then? Is there a different syntax or something?

Comment: I've edited the comment to describe how an iVar is accessed. BTW, what language are you coming from? If it's not a C based one then you'll have to learn about pointers.

Comment: I have been programming C for the last 15 years so I think I know it by heart :) What's confusing me about your explanation is that you say I can access instance variables directly as "someVariable"... so isn't that exactly what I was doing above but it didn't work? I've changed it now to self->mainWindow->contentView but this gives me the following error now: "struct NSWindow" has no member named "contentView" but according to Apple docs this has been available since 10.0 and I'm on 10.4. It's confusing...

Comment: Oh right, it can be used as "someVariable"... the dot syntax was wrong. So I can write mainWindow->contentView and get the "no member named contentView" error now too.... but why?

Comment: If you look at the documentation you'll notice that contentView is a method on NSWindow. However Objective C (starting with 2.0 I think) allows you to "call" methods that return something (i.e are non-void) as properties. And since contentWindow is a method, not an iVar, you need to either use it as a method ([self->mainWindow contentView]) or as a property (self->mainWindow.contentView).

Comment: self->mainWindow.contentView doesn't work here - maybe because I'm still on 10.4 and Xcode 2.1 - but [self->mainWindow contentView] does the trick so everything's working fine now. Thanks a lot!